# Python: how to write a function which depends on external modules

Tags: python-3.x, function

If we write a function which depends on some packages / modules, do we need to `import` all the modules from within function? Or do we somehow (how?) check for dependencies and raise an error / warning? How to do it in efficient manner as the function might be called many-many times? And how do we deal with aliases? I mean if the code that calls the function has imported a required package but used an alias, e.g. `import numpy as np`, how do we access it from within the function?

Comment: Where are you defining this function? How are you expecting it to be used? Basically wherever you define your function you'll need to have imports for any modules it uses.

Comment: @PyPingu Thank you for your comment. I want to save the function (as a module?) so that a user can load it for use. I would not, in general, expect the user to know what dependencies the function has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So looking at your comment I would suggest you have answered your own question. You understand that you don’t expect the user to know about a function’s module dependencies.

You say you want to have this function in a module - let’s call it `my_module` for now.

So you have a file `my_module.py`:

```
#Add any imports code in this module relies on 
import os
import numpy as np 

def my_numpy_func(arg1, arg2):
     #function code using numpy e.g. 
     my_arr = np.array(arg1) 
     #etc etc 
     return result 

def some_other_func():
      #blah blah blah
```

Now anyone who wants to use your function can simply write `from my_module import my_numpy_func` and not have to worry about loading the dependencies.

**Note**: this doesn’t have anything to do with ensuring that a user actually has required non-standard packages installed on their machine. For example if they have not installed `numpy` they will get an `ImportError` when they try to import your function.

If you want to distribute your code and make it so that users don’t need to worry about that, then you probably need to make your code a package that makes the dependencies a requirement on installation.

Comment: Thank you for your post. So, functions cannot be saved by themselves, i.e. just the `def ....` block of code, and need to be saved as modules? And what if the user already has, say, `numpy` package loaded in their code? Will loading the function also load the same package again? Is there a way to avoid this duplication somehow? Thanks

Comment: You don't really need to worry about that. Python uses a [module cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) so any duplicated imports aren't really affecting performance.